# Patch 'this' variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

How do you think, is it ok to rewrite `this` variable in constructor with patched one with jquery? Then you will have some helpful methods for handling events, etc. What advantages, disadvantages it has?

Some example:

```
var Transformer = function(name, rase) {
  this = $(this); // patch `this` with jQuery
  this.name = name;
  this.rase = rase;
}

Transformer.prototype.transform = function() {
  // now we can do that
  this.trigger('transformstart');
}
```

Is this a bad practice?

**UPD**

It's just impossible, you'll have an error:

> ReferenceError: "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Comment: it's not a bad practice, it's just not possible. you cannot have `this` on the left side of an assignment (you cannot `set` `this`).

Comment: further note: I guess it would be a bad practice, if possible ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find helpful to have `$this` field.

```
var Transformer = function(name, rase) {
  this.$this = $(this);
  this.name = name;
  this.rase = rase;
}

Transformer.prototype.transform = function() {
  this.$this.trigger('transformstart');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a jQuery as a events helper, you can make an "events" property:

```
var Transformer = function(name, rase) {
  this.events = $({});
  // other code
}

Transformer.prototype.transform = function() {
  this.events.trigger('transformstart');
}

// public usage
var optimus = new Transformer('Optimus', 'Autobots');
optimus.events.on('transformstart', function() {
  console.log('say hello to my gun!');
});
```